# Eigenvectors - unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Considering that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors, find the values of $a,b,c,d$
:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\1 & c & d\\
1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\qquad v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \\
1 \end{bmatrix}\qquad v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0 \\
-1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am honestly quite confused as to how I can solve this. I tried to find det but I found this:

$c-d-a(1-d)+b(1-c)$

which is not very useful

Comment: What does it mean to be an eigenvector?

Comment: Because you are given that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors, there will exist two numbers (eigenvalues) $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ for which
$$Av_1 = \lambda_1 v_1, \quad Av_2 = \lambda_2 v_2.$$
You then have six unknowns ($a,b,c,d,\lambda_1, \lambda_2$) and six equations.

Comment: 6 equations how? we've got two equations with the λ1,λ2 and 3 equations from matrix A (meaning the rows are 3)

Comment: @notatimelord $Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ is not really just one equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Av_1=\lambda_1v_1\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1+a+b\\1+c+d\\3\end{pmatrix}=\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $Av_2=\lambda_2v_2\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1-b\\1-d\\0\end{pmatrix}=\lambda_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$
Then $\lambda_2=0, b,d=1$. Now we can find $a \text{ and }c$ too.